# Filter Data MySQL

Tags: mysql

I use MySql Server 8.x , and i note a problem with directive AND , OR

in a table I need to filter data based on words contained in a Blob field.
The id_catalog field identifies a set of data, to simplify let's say.
id_catalog = 1 - CatalogA ,id_catalog = 2 - CatalogB, id_catalog = 9 - CatalogC

For example, the word f-104, c-119 recurs in various catalogs

it is my intention to have the words f-14,f-15-c-119 only in catalog 1 and not also on others
in fact I indicate where id_catalog = "1"

Performing the Query

`SELECT * FROM db_catalogo.tb_foto WHERE  db_catalogo.tb_foto.id_catalogo = '1'  AND db_catalogo.tb_foto.tag LIKE '%c-119%' OR db_catalogo.tb_foto.tag LIKE'%f-104%' ORDER BY db_catalogo.tb_foto.id_catalogo, db_catalogo.tb_foto.posizione;`

The query above returns the words yes of catalog "1" but also "9" (where they are present)

I have a feeling that
`OR db_catalogo.tb_foto.tag LIKE'%f-104%`

`it passes the AND condition`
`WHERE`
`db_catalogo.tb_foto.id_catalogo = '1'`

catalogo 1 ha 12 record contenenti le parole c-119 and f-104

the query returns 40 records.

Comment: If the answer you have received is correct, please mark it by clicking the tick mark beside it, green. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses in order to properly evaluate the WHERE condition.

Your query:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  db_catalogo.tb_foto 
WHERE 
  db_catalogo.tb_foto.id_catalogo = '1'  
AND 
  db_catalogo.tb_foto.tag LIKE '%c-119%' 
OR 
  db_catalogo.tb_foto.tag LIKE'%f-104%' 
ORDER BY 
  db_catalogo.tb_foto.id_catalogo, db_catalogo.tb_foto.posizione;
```

It is currently being parsed as

```
WHERE 
  (db_catalogo.tb_foto.id_catalogo = '1'  
   AND 
  db_catalogo.tb_foto.tag LIKE '%c-119%') 
OR 
  db_catalogo.tb_foto.tag LIKE'%f-104%' 
ORDER BY 
  db_catalogo.tb_foto.id_catalogo, db_catalogo.tb_foto.posizione;
```

This allows the `9` values to come through because your `AND` is being processed only for the initial part of your statement (the `WHERE = '1'`). This is happening because of operator precedence. Adding parentheses yourself guarantees that it will properly do what you want.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  db_catalogo.tb_foto 
WHERE 
  db_catalogo.tb_foto.id_catalogo = '1'  
AND 
  (db_catalogo.tb_foto.tag LIKE '%c-119%' 
   OR db_catalogo.tb_foto.tag LIKE'%f-104%') 
ORDER BY 
  db_catalogo.tb_foto.id_catalogo, db_catalogo.tb_foto.posizione;
```

This correctly checks for `WHERE id_catalogo = '1'` first, and then checks the conditions in the `AND` to make sure they also meet the requirements.

For more information, see the MySQL documentation regarding operator precedence.